# Azure AD, Multi-tenant, App Roles Assignment for users from another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working on web application that contains client side (SPA, angular 9) and backend (WebAPI, ASP.NET Core 3.0). Decided to use Application Roles feature to authorize users in our application. And i have requirement to be able to manage Application role assignments for users from our application UI via MSFT Graph API.

1. I registered *MyAuthApp* application in Azure AD *TenantA*. And created several App Roles there.

Authentication works fine. Client side gets token and attaches it to http requests to backend. Authorization also works fine i can extract app roles from the token and validate them.

Problem with adding Application role assignments for users from other AzureAD tenant -- *TenantB*.  Seems that problem in GraphServiceClient configuration due to *GraphApiAuth* registered in *TenantA*.

**Question**: is this possible to add application role assignment for user from *TenantB* using GraphServiceClient authorized by Client Credentials in *TenantA*?
Right now when i do add role assignment i'm getting exception like resource with some Guid not found. This resource is a user (from *TenantB*).
This is a piece of code that adds user app role assignment. I see possible problem in GetGraphServiceClient function. It uses as authority URL with *TenantA* Id.

```
public async Task<AppRoleAssignment> AssignAppRoleToUser(Guid userId, Guid appRoleId)
        {
            var graphClient = await this.graphClientProvider.GetGraphServiceClient();

            return await graphClient.Users[userId.ToString()].AppRoleAssignments.Request().AddAsync(
                new AppRoleAssignment()
                {
                    PrincipalId = userId,
                    AppRoleId = appRoleId,
                    ResourceId = this.graphAppSettingsProvider.GetAppRoleResourceIdAsGuid()
                });
        }
```

[image: Exception i have]

df0b3e71-fd2d-41a4-bfa9-0310b31395ae is Id of user from tenantB.

**UPDATE**:After further investigation i was able to assign App role for user from *TenantB*. But i had to change settings in the code that returns GraphServiceClient and provide *TenantB* Id and Application Service Principal Id from *TenantB* (instead of values from *TenantA*). But that's a problem. We would like to be able to assign application roles for users from any tenant and it will be not doable if we will have to provide TenantId and Service Principal Id for each tenant separately.
**Is it possible to do this some how with some common settings?**
This is how i get GraphServiceClient:

```
public async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphServiceClient()
        {
            var clientId = this.graphAppSettingsProvider.GetClientId();
            var clientSecret = this.graphAppSettingsProvider.GetClientSecret();
            var tenantId = this.graphAppSettingsProvider.GetTenant();

            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .Build();

            string[] scopes = {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"};
            return new GraphServiceClient(
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
                {
                    var ar = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", ar.Result.AccessToken);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }));
        }
```

**UPDATE 2**
Changed a little requirements and now we just need to manage App Roles list for users from current user tenant. So, we changed permissions type from Application to Delegated to be behalf of authenticated user.
As i said earlier we have Angular app in pair with ASP.NET Core WebAPI backend. Angular app gets access token and sends it to backend in Authorizaiton header.  When i attach with access token to GraphServiceClient request (header) i'm getting error "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."
Question: is this correct flow to use access token from client for Graph API requests or should i get new access token for Graph API at backend using access token from client?

Any help/ideas appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the issues you’re running into with app role assignments? Considering app roles are assigned to an enterprise application (which is in other tenant), you should be able to do it. Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: @GauravMantri thank you for your attention. I have added some more details to the question. Main question is this possible to add app role assignment for user from another tenant by GraphClientService autorized with Client Credentials in another tenant.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set up the **MyAuthApp** application as a **multi-tenant application**.

[image]

Next, run admin consent url in the browser, and then you need to log in with another tenant's administrator account and consent. The multi-tenant application will then be added to the target tenant as an **enterprise application**. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}`.

At the same time, the app role you created in tenant A will also be synchronized to the target tenant (for example, tenant B). Next, you only need to grant the app role of **MyAuthApp** to the users of tenant B through the Azure portal of tenant B or use ms graph api.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Carl Zhao i did that. And it works fine if i do this manually. My problem is related to Graph API call and setting app role assignments programmatically.

Comment: @dskibin  What error did you encounter? Please provide detailed error information.

Comment: Resource with *Guid* not found. Guid is Id of User.  @Carl Zhao my question is it possible at all to assign app role for a user from tenant B by graph client authorized in tenant B?

Comment: @dskibin  Are you using this api? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @dskibin  You mean that the app role can be granted to the user in the portal of tenant B, but an error is reported when using graph api? This is strange.
Are you sure that the user is in tenant B? Can you check the user in tenant B and make sure that the guid is the user's object id?

Comment: yes. User is in Tenant B. Will double check Guid now. But i'm sending it from client side and get from active account localAccountId property.

Comment: @dskibin  The easiest way is to use graph api:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: you mean get User via Graph API and use Id from there? Ok, will try to do that, thanks.

Comment: @dskibin    yes,  test it.

Comment: tested. Me graph endpoint returns same Guid as localAccountId property of active account i used before.

Comment: @dskibin  I think you are not the user’s guid error, it is likely that the parameters in the request are not configured correctly. You can refer to this answer to configure the request parameters of the api: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139515/assign-custom-role-to-azure-active-directory-system-managed-identity?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: do you know if i can reuse access token received at client side for Graph API calls from backend?